# Earth Day 2021: thinking about our planet, biology, and sustainability

Tags: discussion

[Earth Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Day) is celebrated this week on April 22nd. The day was created to bring focus to learning about environmental issues and more broadly to discuss the issues faced by any life sharing this planet, us all included.

Our sister site, [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/), is running a [collection of users' sustainable living changes over the past year](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379/earth-day-2021-what-sustainable-living-choices-have-you-made-in-the-past-year) on their site meta.

I'm posting this here to spread interest in their initiative and also to get folks thinking about our planet and our environment this week. The condition of our planet is of critical importance to biology, especially biodiversity, and understanding how global changes in climate affect our ecosystems and species continues to be a critical area for research.

The state of our planet is also of selfish importance to us humans as residents of this rock. Though we are capable of using Earth's resources far beyond sustainable levels, our quality of life as a species now and in the future is critically dependent on how we treat our home.

Comment: Great - thanks for bringing attention to this!